# "Finite" includes Zero?

Tags: terminology

It is accepted that the empty set, of cardinality 0, is a finite set.

So for phrases like "all but finitely many", or there is "a finite number of", is it accepted that they include the 0 possibility? For instance then, "all but finitely many" would be equivalent to "all but at most finitely many", and "a finite number of" would be equivalent to "zero or more but not infinitely many", correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott is there any rule for considering 0 finite/infinite? Does it change depending on the context?

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄: $0$ is always finite.